# Comparing Special Characters using the IF function (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, csv, if-statement

I am trying to compare the values of two cells in two different workbooks (.csv files) that hold special characters (■, □)

The code is to compare the cell content with a reference cell and let the user know if they are the same.

e.g
CASE 1. □□□□□ (FOUND) to ■■■■■ (REFERENCE) --> Different value

CASE 2. ■■■■■ (FOUND) to ■■■■■ (REFERENCE) --> Same value

I have a FOR loop to run through the entries and an IF-statement to perform the comparison. The IF function is suppose check if the cells are equal

Unfortunately, my code keeps determining that the cells are not equal.

i.e CASE 2 keeps producing message feedback "Different Value"

I am unable to find the problem so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

[CODE BELOW]

```
Sub Value_Checker()

Old_Data = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose old data to import", _
FileFilter:="CSV Files *.csv (*.csv), ")

If Old_Data = False Then
    MsgBox "No file specified.", vbExclamation, "Please pick old data"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set OldFile = Workbooks.Open(Old_Data)
End If

Rowlim = 100

ThisWorkbook.Activate

CHECK = Cells(4, 3).Value

OldFile.Activate 'Activates old workbook

For i = 1 To Rowlim
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Select
    If Cells(i, 4) <> CHECK Then
        MsgBox "Different Value"
    Else
        MsgBox "Same Value"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the cells hold the same text? the "square" characters you use in your example are often used for characters which cannot be represented by the current font, so it's possible that multiple (different) characters *appear* to have the same representation on the screen.  Check the ASCII code of each character?  Also check for leading/trailing spaces since "a  " is not equal to "a".

Comment: You might have created an obscure problem by setting CHECK to Cells(x,x).Value instead of Cells(x,x).  The Cell object doesn't have a Value property documented, so it may be referencing the property in the Range object instead and unable to resolve the comparison correctly.  I would try removing the Value property first.

Comment: Ensure your CHECK and test cells are referring to the correct cells on the correct worksheets.  Also, why are you activating and selecting anything?

Comment: @BobRodes You may be confusing with Word.  There is a Cell object in Word, but in Excel, Cells refers to a property of various objects, and returns a Range object. I don't see a Cell object in Excel documented at all

Comment: @BobRodes to add on what Ron says, `Cells(x,y)` returns an `Excel.Range` object which does have a `.Value` property. However, that property is also the default property of a range, so omitting (or including) should yield the same results. The only thing to be careful of is that a cell can potentially contain an Error type, which would raise a Type Mismatch error when comparing to string.

Comment: @DavidZemens & Ron I thought it might be that way, but couldn't find a "smoking gun" in the doc either way.  So ok, not a solution.

Comment: Can you upload a small sample file with somne of these characters to Google docs or drop box?  We may be able to better assist you if we can test using the same characters in excel formatted file.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback.

When I checked the values in my variables, the clear squares return "?" and filled squares return a broken vertical bar.

so 5 clear squares would give me "?????".

I have tried StrComp() but it kept giving me object error.
 
I have solved my problem by simply querying the last character in the string, converting that into an ASCII value and the performing the comparison. (Not the most elegant solution, but it appears to work).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try `strcomp()`:

```
StrComp(Cells(i, 4), CHECK, CompareMethod.Binary)
```

Some more information [here](http://codevba.com/visual-basic-source-code/vb-string/checking_if_two_strings_are_equal.htm).